# About $C^{0,\alpha}$ and subset

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded with $\alpha>1$.

a) Find Hölder spaces

b) $I\in \mathbb{R}$ open and bounded intervall and $\alpha \in ]0,1[$

How do I see $C^1(I)\subset  C^{0,1}(I) \subset C^{0,\alpha}(I) \subset C^0(I)$

c) For $I=]-0.5,0.5[$ with

\begin{equation}
u(x)=
\begin{cases}
-\dfrac1{\log x} &\text {for }  x>0\\
\\ 
0 &\text{for } x\leq0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: Are you trying to see that the inclusions are all strict?

Comment: Yes indeed. They should be strict. I think this is showable on an example?

Comment: Yes, they are indeed strict and there are explicit examples. It's just not clear what exactly you want from the statement of your question.

Comment: Well, i basically wanna see the subsets and then on an example that they are strict.

Comment: You should put that in your question, though I showed the inclusions in my answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C^1$ is contained in $C^{0,1}$ because a bound on the magnitude of the derivative is a Lipschitz constant, and such a bound exists from the extreme value theorem. The inclusion is strict because of things like $|x|$ on $[-1,1]$.

$C^{0,\beta}$ is contained in $C^{0,\alpha}$ for $0<\alpha<\beta \leq 1$ simply because $|x-y|^\beta \leq |x-y|^\alpha$ if $|x-y| \leq 1$. For larger $|x-y|$ you can just repeatedly apply the "local" estimate and concavity will save you, so there is no problem. The inclusion is strict because of things like $|x|^\alpha$ on $[-1,1]$. Note that $C^{0,\gamma}$ for $\gamma>1$ doesn't really make sense, it is a space containing only constants.

It's obvious that the last inclusion holds, but less obvious that it is strict. One way to do it is to just sum over $|x|^\alpha$'s with decaying weights, as in $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} |x|^{1/n}$ on $[-1,1]$.